# In a mobile app, with admob, which is the most profitable way to display banners?

Tags: ios, react-native, admob, adsense

So in my mobile app there is a tab header with several screens. My question is: what's the most profitable way to display banners? I can add a single banner for all pages (admob component on rendered on parent component, same as the tab header) this way, if the user changes tabs it will always display the same ad.

Or I could add a banner on each screen, so it renders on each tab differently. (it could have a different ad on each screen).

So which of these is more profitable? Or is the same? And which of these would you recommend using and why?

Thanks!

** my app was developed using react native!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is really not straight forward. You need to do experiment with different conditions to know what suits your app and users.

Both options are similar. Some users click the ad if they see it repeatedly and some users like to see new ads every time. Experimenting will work best to understand how your users are.

I used to show different ads in every screen because that works best for me.

I've stopped using banner ads. They give damn less revenue and consumes small space from my app. I feel the revenue it gives is not worth the space it takes. Anyway, it's my opinion, yours may be different.